# Java Discord Bot: dont execute code in onGuildVoiceMoveEvent-Listener when Member gets moved by the bot itself

Tags: discord, bots, listener

```
@Override
    public void onGuildVoiceMove(@NotNull GuildVoiceMoveEvent event) {
    }
```

> I want that the code inside this Eventlistener doesnt get executed
> when the bot itself moves the member(not gets moved). I tought of
> using something like this:

```
if(!event.getMover().getUser().isBot()){ //getMover doesn't exist just
                                         //.getMember and .getEntity

//Code
}
```

> But i can't find a way to get the Member/User that moves the Member.
> I'd be very thankful if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: I know this question is old, but i just figured out a way to do this. You can use a boolean that you set to true if the code for moving the member is executed and then check in the event if that boolean is true. If it is you can execute the code you want to. Don't forget to reset the boolean to false as the code in the move event is executed.

Comment: @Redi Hey Thanks for the answer. This seems like a good idea, but im not sure if it causes some super bad bugs, if the user gets moved from annother source in the time the moving operation gets queued and executed. (Bc it would be handled as the bot move)

Comment: Still this is a quite unlikely case and depending of how the threading stuff by discord works this might work fine.

Comment: Maybe we'll get an API endpoint for that in the future. Let's just hope for that.

Comment: That would be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Supported by the Discord JDA / Discord API. You can open a Suggestion Issue [here](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/issues) or a Suggestion for the official Discord API [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000789911-API)